# How do I append to each line of a .txt file using cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

Example in sample.txt I have all the file names inside a certain folder

```
image1.bmp
image2.bmp
image3.bmp
```

Now I want to append a path to it and make another .txt

result.txt

```
C:\sample\image1.bmp
C:\sample\image2.bmp
C:\sample\image3.bmp
```

How do I do that? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (sample.txt) do @echo c:\sample\%%i)>result.txt
```

for use at the command line, use `%i` instead of `%%i`